# How to thank someone for her kindness in welcoming you publically?

Tags: work-environment, etiquette, approach, saying-thanks

I am in a formal setting whereby my superior pleasantly welcomed me in an email (tricky to say it is non-formal, it is formal but in a nice way) among other members. I want to reply to her via email, thanking her that she kindly introduced me to other staff (they are cc'd to the email) and at the same time trying to arrange an informal social meeting (informal, yet it counts as formal, because of superiority) for me with others.

I was about to reply:

> "*thank you for introducing me and arranging a meeting*"

but I felt that this phrase does not show appreciation and is a bit "too" formal.

English isn't my mother tongue. **How can I answer showing appreciation and warmth in a (not too) formal way ?**

Comment: Hi there, welcome to IPS. I've given your post a pretty big edit, hopefully to make it more clear and on-topic for this stack. Please feel free to rollback or edit/clarify if needed.

Comment: If you could add more details about the setting, that'd be nice. Formal is quite subjective, and a whole range of settings could be called formal, but one would be more formal than the other. In order to help you with not being too formal, we need to know more about the formality of the setting other than 'it's formal'. Also, are you speaking to this person one on one, or is the rest of the group you were introduced to present? Are you talking face to face, on the phone/video call, email, something else?

Comment: Last point: did the less informal meeting you mention already get organized, or is this something you're still trying to set up? If it's the latter, what meeting are you referring to in your proposed reply, is that the formal meeting that already happened or?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I adjusted some of the questions you raised but the meeting has not happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer should be timely. Here are a few response options:

> 1. "Thank you for the warm introduction! I look forward to meeting everyone!"
> 2. "Thank you for the introduction!I look forward to meeting everyone!"
> 3. "I appreciate the introduction! I look forward to meeting everyone!"
> 4. "Thank you! Hello everyone! I look forward to meeting!"

Typically, appreciation and gratitude are shown in a timely manner but there is an English phrase that says: "*better late than never!*"